# Processing Java exceptions with AWK

Tags: java, hadoop, awk

I am wondering what is the best approach to collect all the different exceptions that happened from a log file.

An entry look like this:

/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-cmf-hdfs-DATANODE-aaa.log.out.5

```
2017-08-30 13:54:44,561 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataNode{data=FSDataset{dirpath='[/var/hadoop/sdc/dn/current, /var/hadoop/sdd/dn/current]'}, localName='host.tld:50010', datanodeUuid='aaaaaa-6828-44dd-xxx-bbbbb', xmitsInProgress=0}:Exception transfering block BP-111111-172.16.9.110-1471873778315:blk_1086251547_12532682 to mirror 172.16.9.8:50010: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.InvalidEncryptionKeyException: Can't re-compute encryption key for nonce, since the required block key (keyID=-111) doesn't exist. Current key: 123
```

Or this:

```
2016-08-22 15:50:09,706 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer: Disk Balancer is not enabled.
```

I would like to print out the exception or if there is no exception then the remaining fields after $4.

Current code:

```
awk '/ERROR/{print $3" "$4}' /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/*.log.out | sort | uniq -c
```

Is there an easy way to look through all of the fields after $4 and if there is an exception print out the field that has the exception, if there isn't just print out everything?

The output is like this right now:

```
     93 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode:
   8403 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer:
```

The expected output is:

```
     xx ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
     yy ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
   8403 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer: Disk Balancer is not enabled.
```

Sample input:

```
2016-08-22 16:35:42,502 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer: Disk Balancer is not enabled.
2016-08-22 16:36:42,506 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer: Disk Balancer is not enabled.
2016-08-22 16:37:29,515 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DiskBalancer: Disk Balancer is not enabled.
2016-08-22 16:37:29,530 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2018-01-06 13:45:18,899 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: hostname:50010:DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation  src: /172.16.9.68:53477 dst: /172.16.9.6:50010
2018-01-06 14:04:05,176 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataNode{data=FSDataset{dirpath='[/var/hadoop/sdc/dn/current, /var/hadoop/sdd/dn/current]'}, localName='hostname:50010', datanodeUuid='uuid', xmitsInProgress=11}:Exception transfering block BP-1301709078-172.16.9.110-1471873778315:blk_1095601056_21903280 to mirror 172.16.9.34:50010: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 65000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.9.6:37439 remote=/172.16.9.34:50010]
```

Comment: Post 1 sample input file and THE output you expect given that input file. i.e. give us something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: based on your sample log files. shouldn't your expected output include `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.InvalidEncryptionKeyException:` ? Don't make us try to read your mind. Specifications need to be unambiguous ;-) OR reedit your sample input so we know what sort of line will contain `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`, etc Good luck.

Comment: I am working on a multi line anonymized log. Add it here soon.